# Group Theory: Proving that a presentation describes a known group

Tags: group-theory, relations, group-presentation

Say we wish to show that a given group $G$ is described by the presentation $ H = \langle g_1,g_2,\cdots \mid r_1 = r_2 = \cdots = 1\rangle$. My line of reasoning is as follows:

(1) Show by our knowledge of $G$ that suitable generators and relations exist, implying that $|H| \geq |G|$.

(2) Show by some other means that $|H| \leq |G|$. (For example given the relations on $H$ we show that all words in $H$ are necessarily equal to one of a set of $n = |G|$ words).

(3) We now know that $|H| = |G|$.

Can we now conclude that the groups are actually isomorphic, knowing that their orders are the same? Or is some additional information needed?

Comment: Multiple groups can exist of the same order. For example, for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, there exists a cyclic group of order $n$. However, you also have the various cyclic groups $D_{2n}$, which are generally not isomorphic to the cyclic groups and have order of an even positive integer.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer But in this case, we know more than simply that the groups are the same order: We know that the relations of the second are a subset of the relations of the first. My question is if the equality of orders forces this subset relationship to be actual equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, knowing that the orders are the same is very poor information if you've got nothing else.

However, the general way to show that a presentation *is* a presentation is by defining an isomorphism, which means three things:

- a map that is well-defined, and
- injective, and
- surjective.

Now if you know that the orders are the same, **and if the order is finite**, then injectivity is enough, and surjectivity is enough.

However, proving both injectivity and surjectivity might turn out to be easier than showing that the orders are the same to begin with.

If the order is infinite, then knowing that it's the same for both groups is essentially useless.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! Followup question: If we define a group by generators and relations, and we know that the group is finite, then does imposing an additional relation (not implied by the originals) necessarily shrink the group's order?

Comment: Yes. Consider a collection of $n$ generators and relations amongst the generators generating a group $G.$  Now $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $H$ of $F,$ the free group on $n$ generators. Adding a relation induces a subset $H' \subseteq H.$ We cannot have $H' = H$ since this would imply the extra relation was redundant. Thus, the new group $G'$ is isomorphic to $H' \subsetneq H \cong G,$ which implies $|G'| < |G|.$ Note that we had to use the fact that all the groups involved are finite.

Comment: @Displayname Seems we can use this to justify what I was originally asking: If $G$ had any extra relations not implied by those in $H$, it would mean that $G$ has smaller order than $H$ - so if we know the orders are equal, $G$ must have no extra relations, and is therefore isomorphic to $H$.